# RoboEarth rosmake error (updated)

Tags: turtlebot, rosmake, roboearth, ros-electric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(version 1) Ubuntu 10.04; ROS Electric; rosmake roboearth gives error. This problem cannot be solved even by downgrading the svn.

(version 2) Hence, I upgraded my system to Ubuntu 12.04 LTS; ROS Fuerte; also before rosmake, I install this: sudo apt-get install swi-prolog

Now, the problem is missing knowrob_cad_models but I cannot sudo apt-get install nor rosdep install it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59336/roboearth-rosmake-error-(updated)/) by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 229 on 2013-03-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The main developer Daniel Di Marco has updated the rosinstall file. In addition, the followings are required before rosmake:

sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-knowrob

sudo apt-get install swi-prolog

Perhaps someone should modify the ROS wiki.

---

Originally posted by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) with karma: 229 on 2013-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The output points towards the problem: "Failed to find rosdep ..." indicates that system dependencies are missing. Normally, you can install them using rosdep (see http://www.ros.org/wiki/rosdep).

However, you seem to use very old versions (Ubuntu Lucid and ROS Electric) and rosdep has changed, so I'm not sure if this still works for all dependencies. You can still look at the packages mentioned in the error message above and try to install them (or similar Ubuntu packages) manually using apt-get or aptitude.

It may also be that some of the software does not work with Electric, maybe check for earlier questions regarding this here on answers.ros.org.

---

Originally posted by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) with karma: 2673 on 2013-03-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Chik](https://answers.ros.org/users/3814/chik/) on 2013-03-26**:
Hmmm...  I got the TurtleBot just last month but the distributor told me to use Ubuntu 10.04 and ROS Electric. I feel like being cheated by the distributor...

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2013-03-26**:
Well, it's always a trade-off between old and well-used software and new stuff, would not call it cheating. I'd consider switching to Precise/Fuerte if that's supported by the turtlebot.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to install  SWI-Prolog library(missing library)

```
sudo apt-get install swi-prolog
```

then try to `rosmake`

---

Originally posted by [hiranya](https://answers.ros.org/users/3446/hiranya/) with karma: 104 on 2013-03-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1